# How to determine cell in tableview which have a button pressed

Tags: swift, button, tableview, cell

could you please help me to understand how to figure out my situation. I have a table view and cell prototype names 'cellWithButton'. On this cell i have a button. i hold 'control' and drag to view controller to make action for button touch inside. And i cant understand how to determine cell which have a button what was pressed.

i try myself to solve it and find using 'tag'. so set different tag to buttons in time of cellForRowAtIndexPath. but it doesnt work.
What property of the button i can assign during cellForRowAtIndexPath to determine this button in future.

after all i think maybe iam doing something wrong?

Comment: var butMain : UIButton = cell.viewWithTag(200) as! UIButton

Comment: set the button.tag value as IndexPath.Row . This is the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

When i populate tableview in function

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->        UITableViewCell
```

i assign to button on cell prototype any string to 'accessibilityLabel'

```
var buttonOnCell : UIButton = cell.viewWithTag(200) as! UIButton
buttonOnCell.accessibilityLabel = "button number 3"
```

and in action i can access it

```
@IBAction func buttonPressedOnCell(sender: UIButton) {
        println(sender.accessibilityLabel)
    }
```